# Understanding map syntax

Tags: apache-pig

I have some problems understanding how the `map` should be used.

Following this [tutorial](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#map-schema) I created a file containing the following text:

```
[open#apache]
[apache#hadoop]
```

The, I was able to load that file without errors:

```
a = load 'data/file_name.txt' as (M:map [])
```

Now, how can I take the list of all the "*values*"? I.e.

```
(apache)
(hadoop)
```

Furthermore, I have just started to learn Pig, therefore every hints is going to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one way to interact with a map, and that is to use the `#` operator.  In order for it to have more functionality, you'll have to define some [UDFs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/udf.html).  Therefore the only way a map can really be used in pure pig is like:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE M#'open' ;
```

Which produces this as output:

```
(apache)
()
```

Note that the value after the `#` is a quoted string, it cannot change and must be set before the you run the job.

Also, notice that is creates a NULL for the second line, because that map does not contain a key with the vaule 'open'.  This is slightly different then using FILTER on a schema of two chararrays key and value:

```
B = FILTER A BY key=='open' ;
```

Which produces the output:

```
(open,apache)
```

If only the value is desired, then it can be done simply by:

```
B = FOREACH (FILTER A BY key=='open') GENERATE value ;
```

Which produces:

```
(apache)
```

If keeping the NULLs is important, they can also be generated by using a [bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#arithmetic):

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (key=='open'?value:NULL) ;
```

Which produces the same output as `M#'open'`.

From my experience maps are not very useful because of how restrictive they are.