# Transform bag of key-value tuples to map in Apache Pig

Tags: dictionary, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and I want to convert a bag of tuples to a map with specific value in each tuple as key. Basically I want to change:

`{(id1, value1),(id2, value2), ...}` into `[id1#value1, id2#value2]`

I've been looking around online for a while, but I can't seem to find a solution. I've tried:

```
bigQMap = FOREACH bigQFields GENERATE TOMAP(queryId, queryStart);
```

but I end up with a bag of maps (e.g. `{[id1#value1], [id2#value2], ...}`), which is not what I want. How can I build up a map out of a bag of key-value tuple?

Below is the specific script I'm trying to run, in case it's relevant

```
rawlines = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage('`');
bigQFields = FOREACH bigQLogs GENERATE GFV(*,'queryId')
   as queryId, GFV(*, 'queryStart')
   as queryStart;
bigQMap = ?? how to make a map with queryId as key and queryStart as value ?? ;
```

Comment: I've never seen the `GFV` function before, so I'm not sure what it outputs, but is `{(id1, value1),(id2, value2), ...}` part of the resulting schema of `bigQFields`?

Comment: Actually, code you just post the schema for bigQFields, as that is what you want converted to the map, correct?

Comment: Yep. `GFV` is just a UDF I used.

Comment: Just so you know: I simply proposed an enhancement to the existing Pig TOMAP function: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4638

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TOMAP` takes a series of pairs and converts them into the map, so it is meant to be used like:

```
-- Schema: A:{foo:chararray, bar:int, bing:chararray, bang:int}
-- Data:     (John,          27,      Joe,            30)
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOMAP(foo, bar, bing, bang) AS m ;
-- Schema: B:{m: map[]}
-- Data:     (John#27,Joe#30)
```

So as you can see the syntax does not support converting a bag to a map.  As far as I know there is no way to convert a bag in the format you have to map in pure pig.  However, you can definitively write a [java UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#udf-java) to do this.

**NOTE:** I'm not too experienced with java, so this UDF can easily be improved on (adding exception handling, what happens if a key added twice etc.).  However, it does accomplish what you need it to.

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;

public class ConvertToMap extends EvalFunc<Map>
{
    public Map exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        DataBag values = (DataBag)input.get(0);
        Map<Object, Object> m = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        for (Iterator<Tuple> it = values.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Tuple t = it.next();
            m.put(t.get(0), t.get(1));
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Once you compile the script into a jar, it can be used like:

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar ;
-- A is loading some sample data I made
A = LOAD 'foo.in' AS (foo:{T:(id:chararray, value:chararray)}) ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.ConvertToMap(foo) AS bar;
```

Contents of `foo.in`:

```
{(open,apache),(apache,hadoop)}
{(foo,bar),(bar,foo),(open,what)}
```

Output from `B`:

```
([open#apache,apache#hadoop])
([bar#foo,open#what,foo#bar])
```

---

Another approach is to use [python to create the UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#python-udfs):

#### myudfs.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("foo:map[]")
def BagtoMap(bag):
    d = {}
    for key, value in bag:
        d[key] = value
    return d
```

Which is used like this:

```
Register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;
-- A is still just loading some of my test data
A = LOAD 'foo.in' AS (foo:{T:(key:chararray, value:chararray)}) ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myfuncs.BagtoMap(foo) ;
```

And produces the same output as the Java UDF.

---

**BONUS:**
Since I don't like maps very much,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772308/understanding-map-syntax/17773821#17773821) is a link explaining how the functionality of a map can be replicated with just key value pairs.  Since your key value pairs are in a bag, you'll need to do the map-like operations in a nested `FOREACH`:

```
-- A is a schema that contains kv_pairs, a bag in the form {(id, value)}
B = FOREACH A {
    temp = FOREACH kv_pairs GENERATE (key=='foo'?value:NULL) ;
    -- Output is like: ({(),(thevalue),(),()})

    -- MAX will pull the maximum value from the filtered bag, which is 
    -- value (the chararray) if the key matched. Otherwise it will return NULL.
    GENERATE MAX(temp) as kv_pairs_filtered ;
}
```

Comment: Hmm the bonus part looks easy to implement but wouldn't that be much more inefficient than just using a map?

Comment: It is, but I'm not sure by how much.  But for what you are losing in efficiency, you make up for in flexibility.  You can extract out both the key and value, extract out multiple values in one go, `FLATTEN` it, use a variable in the line instead of a quoted string to get a value, etc.  While saving you from having to write any Java (which may or may not be a plus depending on how much you like Java).

Comment: @Penguinator However, If I had to convert the bag to a map then I'd use a python UDF (which I have just updated my answer to include an example of).

Comment: +1 This is great. I think a map is better conceptually but I didn't want to create a dependency on a jar.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation so I submitted a patch that just got accepted: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4638

This means that what you wanted is a core part starting with pig 0.16.