# Combining Multiple Maps together in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am using pig for the first time. I've gotten to the point where I have exactly the answer I want, but in a weirdly nested format:

```
{(price,49),(manages,"1d74426f-2b0a-4777-ac1b-042268cab09c")}
```

I'd like the output to be a single map, without any wrapping:

```
[price#49, manages#"1d74426f-2b0a-4777-ac1b-042268cab09c"]
```

I've managed to use `TOMAP` to get this far, but I can't figure out how to merge and flatten it away.

```
{([price_specification#{"amount":49,"currency":"USD"}]),([manages#"newest-nodes/1d74426f-2b0a-4777-ac1b-042268cab09c"])}
```

How should I be going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no built-in functions to do this for you. You'll have to write your own UDF. Fortunately, this is a simple one.

The `exec` method would just go something like:

```
public Map<String, Object> exec(Tuple input) {
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        m.putAll((Map<String, Object>) input.get(i));

    return m;
}
```

The UDF could take any number of maps as arguments.

Note that if two or more maps share a key, then the final one encountered will be the one that is kept and the others get overwritten.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up finding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847970/transform-bag-of-key-value-tuples-to-map-in-apache-pig after many, many google searches.  It suggests the same answer you have, using a UDF (although it uses python as the language).  That answer did end up working for me.