# Pig LOADER for SPLUNK like records

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, splunk

I am trying to use PIG to read data from HDFS where the files contain rows that look like:

```
"key1"="value1", "key2"="value2", "key3"="value3"
"key1"="value10", "key3"="value30"
```

In a way the rows of the data are essentially dictionaries:

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
{"key1":"value10", "key3":"value30"}
```

I can read and dump portion of this data easily enough with something like:

```
data = LOAD '/hdfslocation/weirdformat*' as PigStorage(',');
sampled = SAMPLE data 0.00001;
dump sampled;
```

My problem is that I can't parse it efficiently.  I have tried to use

```
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader
```

but it seems extremely slow.

Could someone recommend a different approach?

Comment: What is your final output?. one option is you can use STRSPLIT function.

Comment: you mean the output of the LOAD,SAMPLE,DUMP?

Comment: it dumps exactly the input,

Comment: it dumps the input:

    "key1"="value1", "key2"="value2", "key3"="value3"
    "key1"="value10", "key3"="value30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like one way is to use a python UDF.
This solution is  heavily inspired from [bag-to-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847970/transform-bag-of-key-value-tuples-to-map-in-apache-pig)

In `myudfs.py` write:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def FieldPairsGenerator(dataline):
    for x in dataline.split(','):
        k,v = x.split('=')
        yield (k.strip().strip('"'),v.strip().strip('"'))

@outputSchema("foo:map[]")
def KVDataToDict(dataline):
    return dict( kvp for kvp in FieldPairsGenerator(dataline) )
```

then write the following Pig script:

```
REGISTER 'myudfs.py' USING jython AS myfuncs;
data = LOAD 'whereyourdatais*.gz' AS (foo:chararray);
A = FOREACH data GENERATE myfuncs.KVDataToDict(foo);
```

`A` now has the data stored as a `PigMap`

Comment: PS:  you might need some additional conditional statements in your generator depending on how ugly your data is